# Getting Limit error while plotting Contour

Tags: octave

I entered this

```
contour(theta0_vals, theta1_vals , J_vals,logspace(-2,3,20));
```

Octave showed me this error.

```
error: axis: LIMITS(1) must be less than LIMITS(2)
error: called from
axis>__axis__ at line 313 column 9
axis at line 155 column 7
__contour__ at line 198 column 5
contour at line 74 column 16
```

Comment: Please update the title of the question to capture the issue at hand. As written, the title is so vague as to be useless. It does not contribute to the value of this site.

Comment: What could be a suitable title?

Comment: "Error (something) when doing (something)." You fill in the "something"s.

Answer (score 0):

The `contour` function calculates contours and then creates a figure to display them.

When it creates the figure, it attempts to set the axis limits automatically from the minimum and maximum values of the grid in each dimension <sub>(this happens at line 198 of **contour**.m, as per the reported error)</sub>.

If the size of the grid in a particular dimension is singular, then the minimum and maximum are the same number, which results in an error when trying to display this, since you cannot specify an axis width of 0 for a plot or surface.

Observe:

```
>> [X, Y] = ndgrid(0, -5:5);  % X results in a 1x11 vector
>> contour(X,Y,Y)
error: axis: LIMITS(1) must be less than LIMITS(2)
error: called from
    axis>__axis__ at line 313 column 9
    axis at line 155 column 7
    __contour__ at line 198 column 5
    contour at line 74 column 16
```

So your `theta0_vals` or `theta1_vals` variables are either scalars or singular in one dimension. This makes no sense for use as a grid anyway so either this is the result of a but, or if this was intended behaviour you will probably have to rethink what you're doing here.

Comment: Also, much of this is educated guesswork since you give no specific information. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) whenever asking such a question, so you can get a more useful answer. (Let alone that more often than not, the question gets answered by itself in the process of creating one).